# Removing duplicate elements in a Seq

Tags: haskell

wondering how to implement `nub` over a `Seq a`

I get that one could do:

```
nubSeq :: Seq a -> Seq a
nubSeq = fromList . nub . toList
```

Just wondering is there something standard that does not convert to Lists in order to call `nub :: [a]->[a]`?

An implementation that occurred to me, based obviously on nub, is:

```
nubSeq :: (Eq a) => Seq a -> Seq a
nubSeq = Data.Sequence.foldrWithIndex 
           (\_ x a -> case x `Data.Sequence.elemIndexR` a of
                        Just _ -> a
                        Nothing -> a |> x) Data.Sequence.empty
```

But there must be something more elegant?

thanks.

Comment: what do you not like about your `nubSeq` it seems fine to me. If you worry about performance, I'd suggest benchmarking with [`criterion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) and if you really want to be thorough - `--dump-simpl` the output of both versions and compare them.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether this qualifies as more elegant but it splits the concerns in independent functions (caveat: you need an `Ord` constraint on `a`):

- `seqToNubMap` takes a `Seq` and outputs a `Map` associating to each `a` the smallest index at which it appeared in the sequence
- `mapToList` takes a `Map` of values and positions and produces a list of values in increasing order according to the specified positions
- `nubSeq` combines these to generate a sequence without duplicates

The whole thing should be O(n*log(n)), I believe:

```
module NubSeq where

import Data.Map      as Map
import Data.List     as List
import Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Function

seqToNubMap :: Ord a => Seq a -> Map a Int
seqToNubMap = foldlWithIndex (\ m k v -> insertWith min v k m) Map.empty

mapToList :: Ord a => Map a Int -> [a]
mapToList = fmap fst . List.sortBy (compare `on` snd) . Map.toList

nubSeq :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
nubSeq = Seq.fromList . mapToList . seqToNubMap
```

Or a simpler alternative following @DavidFletcher's comment:

```
nubSeq' :: forall a. Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
nubSeq' xs = Fold.foldr cons nil xs Set.empty where

  cons :: a -> (Set a -> Seq a) -> (Set a -> Seq a)
  cons x xs seen
    | x `elem` seen = xs seen
    | otherwise     = x <| xs (Set.insert x seen)

  nil :: Set a -> Seq a
  nil _ = Seq.empty
```

Comment: Using `HashMap` instead of `Map` can potentially improve performance.

Comment: If you are already using a different data structure why not `Seq.fromList . Set.toList . Set.fromList . Seq.toList`?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe - because it does not preserve the ordering - you dummy

Comment: I thought you were pretty rude until I realised you were answering to yourself. :D

Comment: `Map` and sorting does seem like overkill though.  How about just going through the sequence keeping a `Set` of elements seen so far?

Comment: Martin Erwig has a page about this basic pattern. Nice explanatory .gif and background reading for those interested. http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/meta/

Answer (score 0):

Another way with an `Ord` constraint - use a scan to make the sets of
elements that appear in each prefix of the list.  Then we can filter out
any element that's already been seen.

```
import Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Set as Set

nubSeq :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
nubSeq xs = (fmap fst . Seq.filter (uncurry notElem)) (Seq.zip xs seens)
  where
    seens = Seq.scanl (flip Set.insert) Set.empty xs
```

Or roughly the same thing as a mapAccumL:

```
nubSeq' :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
nubSeq' = fmap fst . Seq.filter snd . snd . mapAccumL f Set.empty
  where
    f s x = (Set.insert x s, (x, x `notElem` s))
```

(If I was using lists I would use Maybes instead of the pairs with
Bool, then use catMaybes instead of filtering.  There doesn't seem to be catMaybes
for Sequence though.)

Answer (score -2):

I think your code should be pretty efficient. Since Sequences are tree data structures using another tree type data structure like Map or HashMap to store and lookup the previous items doesn't make too much sense to me.

Instead i take the first item and check it's existence in the rest. If exists i drop that item and proceed the same with the rest recursively. If not then construct a new sequence with first element is the unique element and the rest is the result of nubSeq fed by the rest. Should be typical. I use ViewPatterns.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
import Data.Sequence as Seq

nubSeq :: Eq a => Seq a -> Seq a
nubSeq (viewl -> EmptyL)    = empty
nubSeq (viewl -> (x :< xs)) | elemIndexL x xs == Nothing = x <| nubSeq xs
                            | otherwise                  = nubSeq xs

*Main> nubSeq . fromList $ [1,2,3,4,4,2,3,6,7,1,2,3,4]
fromList [6,7,1,2,3,4]
```